# apigee baas example has a syntax error

Tags: apigee-baas

The Hello World example on the [apigee](http://docs.apigee.com/app-services/content/querying-your-data) site has a quote mismatch error:

```
var dataClient = new Apigee.Client({
    orgName:'your-org', //your Apigee organization name
    appName:'your-app'
});         

var options = {
    endpoint:"users", //the collection to query
    qs:{ql:"status='active'",limit:5"} //the query string - note the use of the 'ql' property
};

//Call request to initiate the API call
dataClient.request(options, function (error, response) {
    if (error){
        //error
    } else {
        //success
    }   
});
```

Q: Is there any hope that this will run once I remove the " after the 5?

Comment: Um... What happens when you try to run after removing it?

Comment: Which SDK is this found in? URL link (to the platform not cURL) would be great!

Comment: It's the JavaScript HTML5 tab [here](http://docs.apigee.com/app-services/content/querying-your-data). @remus

Comment: Ah ok. Yes, it shouldn't have any problems if you remove they quote. Feel free to leave feedback on that docs page too with the error.